# How do we improve tag wiki proposals rather than just 'approve', 'reject' or 'skip' them?

Tags: support

In reviewing a proposed tag definition the page says that we can 'approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users'. However, I cannot see how to 'improve', there only seem to be options for reject, approve or skip. How do we improve tag wiki proposals?

Comment: Yes, I ran across this today, too. It seems normally silly. So, since I believe tags are generally a bad idea in linguistic SEs anyway, I hereby announce a policy of rejecting all tags I am asked to review.

Comment: @jlawler See my answer about that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for improving Tag Wiki edits but it's a privilege (like others) so it is gained by reputation.

The reputation threshold for us is [4000](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user), a graduated site will need 20000 if I'm right.

The rationale for this is that you cannot improve what you cannot create being unsupervised. I.e. if you need someone else to approve your creations, you cannot improve there. See [Allow 'improve' for Tag Wiki Edit Suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95520/176533).

Tags are needed to classify questions for ease of reference and also for ease of understanding. If tags are used badly, they lose all their usefulness. Rejecting all reviews indiscriminately is not going to help us. I suggest doing this:

1. If the "mistake" you'd like to improve is minor, approve and then re-submit an edit yourself (to correct the mistake or even improve with more info, etc).
2. If the mistake is major, i.e. it's plain wrong or poorly formatted, etc, then reject and re-submit a similar edit (perhaps the idea was good in that one). If you decide to simply reject, you can of course. This is just a suggested course of action.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. But it is confusing seeing the reference to an option to improve tag wiki edits.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I didn't even know there wasn't an improve button, never noticed. :P Where is the reference? During the reviewing?

Comment: That means that in a beta situation like LSE, practically nobody has the status to edit tags as they're being set up, which in turn explains a great deal of why they're such a mess.

Comment: @jlawler No, everybody can edit tag wikis. The only difference is that those above 4K can do it without being approved, the others need to be approved (as for edits). Tags can be created by anyone with 150+ reputation.

Comment: As I said, that explains a great deal.

Comment: @jlawler How does it exactly?

Comment: @Alenanno There's no button, just a bit of text that says (something like) 'you can approve, reject or improve...'. Because of that I searched for a way to improve the proposal. It wasn't good enough to approve, but the changes to fix it were minor so rejecting it and redoing it seemed silly...

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I can't think of a better way to do it at the moment, sorry. :P

Answer (score 1):

You've identified an interesting problem that we're looking into.

To do a proper tag wiki /review, you need three abilities:

- Reject the edit ("This does not work.")
- Approve the edit ("Excellent changes, thanks.")
- Improve the edit ("Great start, but needs a few tweaks.")

Unfortunately, not all users doing tag wiki reviews have the reputation to *edit* them properly (hence the missing option).

**We need to bring those reputation abilities into alignment.**

Short term, we're looking into either raising the tag wiki /review threshold so users have the reputation to perform them properly, or… to lower the reputation required to do those edits to broaden the base. Potential solutions are currently under review.

Longer term, there are ways of allowing reviews by lower-rep users (e.g. some sort of *suggested edit* interface), but those will take more thought and development than an immediate solution will allow.

Good catch!

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear.

Comment: Ah didn't know about this. Thanks Robert.